# Can't insert array variables into MySQL DB from $_POST input

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, insert

as always, I have tried to research and solve the problem based on already existing questions but can't wrap my head around it. I am probably doing many things wrong. In the html form, I have input types text,number, title, as well as textarea, so maybe that might account for things not working too?

Here's a link to the thing I'm trying to build: http://postimg.org/image/9mgm6l9hj/

Here's my INSERT query function

```
    function register_hangout($register_hangout_data) {
    array_walk($register_hangout_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $hangout_fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_hangout_data)) . '`';
    $hangout_data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_hangout_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hangouts ($hangout_fields) VALUES ($hangout_data)");
}
```

And here's the code, which, as of now, it does redirect me to hangout.php?success, but doesn't echo "Successssss" or insert into the DB:

```
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('title','dd' ,'mm','yyyy', 'hour', 'minutes', 'location', 'aim', 'description');
    foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required.';
            break 1;
        }
    }  

    print_r($errors);
}

?> 

<?php 
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Successssssss.';
} else {
  // there's one curly brace after the html form tied to this else right above
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        //insert hangout data in mysql database
        $register_hangout_data = array(
            'title'             => $_POST['title'],
            'dd'                => $_POST['dd'],
            'mm'                => $_POST['mm'],
            'yyyy'              => $_POST['yyyy'],
            'hour'              => $_POST['hour'],
            'minutes'           => $_POST['minutes'],
            'location'          => $_POST['location'],
            'aim'               => $_POST['aim'],
            'description'       => $_POST['description']
            );
        register_hangout($register_hangout_data);
        header('Location: hangout.php?success');
        // exit
    }
    elseif (empty($errors) === false) {
        //output errors
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
```

I can't get my head around why these aren't even inserted into the DB, let alone using proper integer functions, sanitization, proper date time functions and format, so please help me solve my actual problem before diving into what other things I should do to this code.

Comment: Why you guys keep using deprecated mysql_*? I see it in almost every question.

Comment: As mentioned by @Inurosen, [**mysql_* functions should be avoided**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). You should also take a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Hi Inurosen. I have been learning a lot on my own, I'm still very much a beginner and don't understand many things. So I followed some online tutorials for a login and registration system because the guy was a very good teacher, it only happened that the videos were old, 2012. I simply extrapolated code from there onwards. Deprecated, non-deprecated, I am looking to understand programming logic for now and simply be able to make things functional, I wouldn't use it in a real world app. Hope this makes sense to more advanced programmers and they forgive me.

Comment: Also, I am a virgin, PHP is my first and we're only at second base.

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other? you're also not checking for errors here.

Comment: Fred, I can confirm the connection works. If anything, I am using xampp and phpmyadmin, but the connections and queries like create database and tables are written straight into the code.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok, now I know (edit, you deleted your comment about the connection being mysql_) Edit #2, you re-added it below. We also have no idea where those POST arrays are coming from or if they hold values. Your query could also contain errors, which I suspect it does. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what MySQL API means, but based on what I read, I'll assume this is what you're talking about? 

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die($connect_error);

Comment: so, my comment above yours here, yielded anything? about error reporting/checking.

Comment: The $_POST array comes from, well, the form below my code with method="post", which is tied to that else where I commented in the code, as you can see. If it is any help, once submitted, this query works for example:
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO hangouts (title), VALUES (' ".$_POST['title']." ') "); And then, when I tried the same query with dd and $_POST['dd'], it wouldn't work. dd field is INT, not VARCHAR.

Comment: Oh well, I added your suggestions, the code works like before, it "successfully" redirects me to hangout.php?success with no error reporting, but still doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: What is the exact query being executed? Can you either get it from MySQL general log, or dump the value of `"INSERT INTO hangouts ($hangout_fields) VALUES ($hangout_data)"`?

Comment: yeah, it's calling the function you see above.

Comment: Start by **checking for errors!** `mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Is anybody willing to spend some 10 minutes with me on teamviewer please... ?